# Short question: Fourier Coefficients

Tags: functions, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a function that is $2\pi$-periodic satisfying $f(x) = x^2$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$ and $f(\pi) = 100$ i.e. it's repeating $x^2$ and $100$ on both endpoints. This function is continuous on $(-\pi, \pi)$, but can we compute its fourier coefficients?

i.e. is it integrable on $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Comment: The function is integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ because it is bounded. Note that when computing the Fourier coefficients, you can ignore the fact that $f(\pi)=100$ and instead consider $f(\pi) = \pi^2$, since the points at which $f$ assumes the value 100 are of measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find this helpful.
Yes, the function (f(x)) you've defined is integrable on ([-π, π]). The function (f(x) = x^2) is a polynomial, which is smooth and hence integrable on its domain. The function (f(x) = 100) is a constant function, which is also integrable. Since (f(x)) is a piecewise combination of these two functions, it is also integrable.

The Fourier coefficients of a function (f(x)) are given by:

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{π} \int_{-π}^{π} f(x) \cos(nx) dx, \quad n \geq 0
$$

$$
b_n = \frac{1}{π} \int_{-π}^{π} f(x) \sin(nx) dx, \quad n > 0
$$

For the function (f(x) = x^2) on ([-π, π]), the Fourier coefficients can be computed directly from these formulas. However, because (f(x)) is not continuous at (x = π), the Fourier series may not converge to (f(x)) at this point. Instead, it will converge to the average of the limit from the left and the limit from the right, which is ((\lim_{x \to π^-} f(x) + \lim_{x \to π^+} f(x))/2 = (π^2 + 100)/2).

In conclusion, while the function (f(x)) is integrable and its Fourier coefficients can be computed, the Fourier series may not represent the function exactly at the discontinuity. This is a manifestation of Gibbs phenomenon, a common occurrence in Fourier analysis when dealing with functions that have jump discontinuities.